# Can't upload to arduino from clion

Tags: arduino-uno, compilation-errors

I'm trying to upload a script to my arduino uno (mega and nano doesn't work either). It works unless I `#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>`

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <SimpleDHT.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET  4

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

// initializing foo here. const static unsigned char foo_bits[] PROGMEM = {0x00, 0x00 ///

void draw(void) {
    display.drawXBitmap( 0, 0,foo_bits, foo_width, foo_height, 1);
    display.display();
}


void setup(void) {
    display.begin();
    display.clearDisplay();
}

void loop(void) {
    draw();
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
libuno_Adafruit_SSD1306.a(Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp.obj): In function `Adafruit_SSD1306::ssd1306_command(unsigned char)':
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `TwoWire::write(unsigned char)'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `TwoWire::write(unsigned char)'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `TwoWire::endTransmission()'
libuno_Adafruit_SSD1306.a(Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp.obj): In function `Adafruit_SSD1306::begin(unsigned char, unsigned char, bool)':
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `SPIClass::begin()'
libuno_Adafruit_SSD1306.a(Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp.obj): In function `SPIClass::beginTransaction(SPISettings)':
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `SPIClass::interruptMode'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `SPIClass::interruptMode'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `SPIClass::interruptSave'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `SPIClass::interruptMask'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `SPIClass::interruptSave'
libuno_Adafruit_SSD1306.a(Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp.obj): In function `Adafruit_SSD1306::begin(unsigned char, unsigned char, bool)':
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:416: undefined reference to `TwoWire::begin()'
libuno_Adafruit_SSD1306.a(Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp.obj): In function `Adafruit_SSD1306::display()':
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:472: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:472: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:472: undefined reference to `TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)'
libuno_Adafruit_SSD1306.a(Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp.obj): In function `TwoWire::write(int)':
/opt/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:78: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:78: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:78: undefined reference to `TwoWire::write(unsigned char)'
libuno_Adafruit_SSD1306.a(Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp.obj): In function `Adafruit_SSD1306::display()':
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:475: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:475: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:475: undefined reference to `TwoWire::write(unsigned char)'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:479: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:479: undefined reference to `Wire'
/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp:479: undefined reference to `TwoWire::endTransmission()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My cMake file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake)
set(PROJECT_NAME touch)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
include_directories(/opt/arduino/arduino-1.8.5/libraries/)
set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_SKETCH touch.ino)

set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD uno)
set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_PORT /dev/ttyACM0)
generate_arduino_firmware(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
```

If I remove all of the `Adafruit_SSD1306` uploading works. The exact same program works from Arduino IDE. What could be the cause and how can I fix this?

Comment: It seems that your posted sketch doesn't match with yours error messages. You never declared those foo_* variables. Did you update your libraries?

Comment: The foo variables are all declared (see the commented line in the sketch, just wanted to keep the code short and foo_bytes is quite long). The sketch works from Arduino IDE and the libraries are updated. @LookAlterno

Comment: @LookAlterno But yeah - I don't see any kind of connection between sketch and error too, what makes this very hard to fix for me...

Comment: The error is in the library, not in your sketch. That's happens from time to time. Your code compile fine in my machine (after adding foo_* definitions) using Arduino 1.8.5 and UECIDE 0.9.1. Patience.

Comment: Patience? For what? @LookAlterno

Comment: There are some brilliant people here. Wait for them